# Member's name in WebsPhere cluster at runtime

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing

I am trying to gets the member's name of member in WebSphere cluster. I can get the hostname, and node name from from AdminService

```
AdminService adminService = AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService();
```

but i am not able from admin service to get member's name. I found that this is providing by cluster mbean in websphere, but i can't find any code examples how can i get this cluster mbean and use in my javacode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *process name* will return the name of the application server (cluster member), which can be obtained from the [`AdminService`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fmanagement%2FAdminService.html).

```
AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService().getProcessName()
```